# libuvc_cam : issue about running the driver

Tags: ros, libuvc-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have follow the instructions in [libuvc_camera](http://wiki.ros.org/libuvc_camera), run the launch file as

```
<node pkg="libuvc_camera" type="camera_node" name="usb_cam">
<!-- Parameters used to find the camera -->
<param name="vendor" value="0x199e"/>
<param name="product" value="0x8302"/>
<param name="serial" value="3"/>
<!-- If the above parameters aren't unique, choose the first match: -->
<param name="index" value="0"/>
<!-- Image size and type -->
<param name="width" value="640"/>
<param name="height" value="480"/>
<!-- choose whichever uncompressed format the camera supports: -->
<param name="video_mode" value="uncompressed"/> 
<param name="frame_rate" value="60"/>
<param name="timestamp_method" value="start"/>
<param name="camera_info_url" value="file:///.../*.yaml"/>
<param name="auto_exposure" value="1"/> <!-- use aperture_priority auto exposure -->
<param name="auto_white_balance" value="false"/>
</node>
```

the terminal came out the following information at last few lines :

unsupported descriptor subtype: 13
uvc_get_stream_ctrl_format_size: Invalid mode (-51)
and
process has died

Does any body could provide any clue to solve this issue? Thank you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201451/libuvc_cam-:-issue-about-running-the-driver/) by [JasonGuee](https://answers.ros.org/users/21439/jasonguee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-01-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That definitely seems like an error related to the settings at the bottom of your launch file. If the height, width, frame_rate, video_mode, etc. that you specify are not supported by your webcam, then the `camera_node` will crash with the error you pasted.

As mentioned in the documentation you linked, you should run the `v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext` command to determine the acceptable values for each of those parameters. If adjusting the parameters doesn't fix the issue, please post the output of this command. Note that you may need to use `--device` along with `v4l2-ctl` to specify which camera to provide parameters for. For more help run `v4l2-ctl --help`

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2015-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mjedmonds](https://answers.ros.org/users/25410/mjedmonds/) on 2016-01-04**:
I'm having the same error using an Intel RealSense R200 camera. Here's my launch file, output, and v4l2-ctl output for the video streams: http://pastebin.com/K3V8ZKL6. Any tips/help are appreciated!